# Strange IE bug on hover updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

http://jsfiddle.net/4t6j5/2/ (this seems to be working normally)

http://www.periferi.nu/#filter=.utstallningar (this does not)

Se the jsFiddle where I have tried to reproduce the error using the parts that are erroneous.

So the problem is that in IE8 and down the read more element starts jumping a whole lot instead of simply sliding in from below when the mouse is over the image. Works perfect in most modern browsers but in IE8 and down it starts jumping (especially when hovering the p elements, for some reason).

It appears that when the code from that part is isolated it works.

Why does it behave differently in IE? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Long shot - maybe it's issue with css not being reset? This would explain why in jsfiddle it works correctly (they use css reset).

Comment: I'm actually using Boilerplate CSS reset on my site

Comment: The real page also works in IE7 (strangest of it all) but not in IE9 and IE8. I've discovered a coincidence - some button elements cannot be clicked upon. And some wont react to hover. However the buttons all work in IE7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after endless hours I have captured the bug in my css file. Strange case but thanks WTK for the direction. Turns out:

```
 html {overflow-y:scroll;}
```

Was the main problem for some for me unknown reason.
If someone sits on further information as of why this happens in IE please share.

http://jsfiddle.net/4t6j5/3/ (Bug hunting fiddle)